# Returning a filtered list of items from where the ID is in a list from another array of matching guids

Tags: list, vb.net, linq, filter, where-clause

After a bit of help to get the a list filtered using another list of items. Ordinarily I'd of coded around this in SQL, but I need to try to get this working in .NET.
I have a list of Roles, and each of these would have a set of permissions on a per page basis, and a user would also be a member of a set of roles, which would be the filter. I'm trying to get my head around a the various help files, but none have examples in this format that I can find.

```
Partial Class TestUsers
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Roles.Role = New List(Of Role)
        Roles.Role.Add(New Role(New Guid("EAC49E8F-BF55-44FD-BE69-5BBF7B5F289A"), "Admin", 0))
        Roles.Role.Add(New Role(New Guid("A174A3ED-17F8-4450-9B25-3D2A21FCDDFF"), "User", 0))
        Roles.Role.Add(New Role(New Guid("5780C40C-111A-4B4D-AA20-80E944B6B67A"), "Anon", 0))
        Roles.Role.Add(New Role(New Guid("7E1DC89C-4B9C-49F8-9A37-0FA22A7C8116"), "HR", 0))

        Dim UserPermission As New List(Of Role)
        UserPermission.Add(Roles.GetRoleByID(New Guid("EAC49E8F-BF55-44FD-BE69-5BBF7B5F289A")))
        UserPermission.Add(Roles.GetRoleByID(New Guid("A174A3ED-17F8-4450-9B25-3D2A21FCDDFF")))

        Dim PagePermission = RolePermission.GetPermissionFromString("Admin:1,1,1;User:1,0,0;Data:1,0,0;")
        Dim FilteredList = PagePermission.Where(Function(i) UserPermission.Contains(i.Role)).ToList
        Response.Write(FilteredList(0).Role.RoleName)

        Response.Write(UserPermission.Count())
        Response.Write("<br>")
        Response.Write(PagePermission.Count())
        Response.Write("<br>")
        Response.Write(FilteredList.Count())
    End Sub
    Public Class RolePermission
        Public Role As Role
        Public Read As Boolean
        Public Edit As Boolean
        Public Admin As Boolean
        Public Sub New(Role As Role, Read As String, Edit As String, Admin As String)
            Me.Role = Role
            Me.Read = Read
            Me.Edit = Edit
            Me.Admin = Admin
        End Sub
        Public Shared Function GetPermissionFromString(Permission As String) As List(Of RolePermission)
            Dim u As New List(Of RolePermission)
            If Permission = "" Then Permission = "Anon:0,0,0;"
            Dim l As String() = Permission.TrimEnd(";").Split(";")
            For Each s In l
                If Not IsNothing(s.Split(":")) Then
                    u.Add(New RolePermission(Roles.GetRoleByName(DbStr(Permission.Split(":")(0))), s.Split(":")(1).Split(",")(0), s.Split(":")(1).Split(",")(1), s.Split(":")(1).Split(",")(2)))
                End If
            Next
            Return u
        End Function
    End Class
    Public Class Role
        Public RoleID As Guid
        Public RoleName As String
        Public SiteGroupID As Integer
        Public Sub New(RoleID As Guid, RoleName As String, SiteGroupID As Integer)
            Me.RoleID = RoleID
            Me.RoleName = RoleName
            Me.SiteGroupID = SiteGroupID
        End Sub
    End Class
    Public Class Roles
        Public Shared Role As List(Of Role)
        Public Shared Function GetRoleByID(RoleID As Guid) As Role
            Return Role.Find(Function(s) s.RoleID = RoleID)
        End Function
        Public Shared Function GetRoleByName(RoleName As String) As Role
            Return Role.Find(Function(s) s.RoleName = RoleName)
        End Function
    End Class
End Class
```

Filtered list is returning 3, it should be two.

```
Dim FilteredList = PagePermission.Where(Function(i) UserPermission.Contains(i.Role)).ToListResponse.Write(FilteredList(0).Role.RoleName)
```

Comment: As I read your post, your expected counts for `FilteredList.Count()` is 2, but you are actually getting 3. Is that correct? I scanned the code and didn't see anything obvious, but do have a few questions: Since there is no "Data" role in the Roles collection, what does `GetRoleByName("Data")` return? Null? Does `PagePermission.Count()` = 2 or 3? What is the result of `UserPermission.Contains(null)`? If the "Data" entry is not the problem. I suggest you try adding and removing data values in the various collections until you isolate the problem.

Comment: Yeah, it was the typo, basically takes the inputs and only returns the permission for the page where it matches the user role.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in `RolePermission.GetPermissionFromString()`. Where you've got `DbStr(Permission.Split(":")(0))`, it should be `DbStr(s.Split(":")(0))`.

Comment: Cheers Darryl, sometimes just needs a second eye to spot these things!

Comment: @GavinClayton, seems like that is something that should have been picked up when debugging. A lot of beginners don't know how to debug or even that it's something they need to do. If that's you, you should stop what you're doing and learn how to debug now. Stepping through that code and examining each reference would have shown you that that was not the value you expected.